# Android Device Connector Plugin not found in Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, plugins

I'm trying to install [Android Device Connector Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Device+connector+plugin) in Jenkins.

But i can't find this plugin on my Jenkins or from there http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/.

I only found for iOS Device Connector plugin.

How to use this plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the hpi file here and upload it under the Advanced section of the Plugin Manager. It works fine for me on Jenkins 2.33. Make sure adb is in your path on your nodes:

https://github.com/xfreebird/android-device-connector-plugin/releases